# Do PynamoDB support AWS DAX?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using PynamoDB for accessing my AWS DynamoDB tables, Now I need to implement the caching via [AWS DAX](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) .

Does PynamoDB support DAX , even if some source code changes are required to make it work , I can do it myself too.
Kindly guide me accordingly.

Comment: There's a possibly related open issue on PynamoDB's github page (https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB/issues/210) and a still unmerged PR to add DAX support (https://github.com/pynamodb/PynamoDB/pull/470).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked from [uncovertruth/PynamoDB](https://github.com/uncovertruth/PynamoDB) which added the support for DAX.
you can install it with

```sh
pip install dynamodb-dax
```

usage example here

```py
class CacheModel(Model):
    """
    A DynamoDB Caching table
    """
    class Meta:
        table_name = "cachingDax"
        region = 'us-east-1'
        dax_read_endpoints = ['example.cache.amazonaws.com:8111']
        dax_write_endpoints = ['example.cache.amazonaws.com:8111']
    cacheKey = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    data = JSONAttribute(default={})
```

### Note:

- The dax endpoints must be a **list** of strings
- You must be in the same VPC as the Dax cluster